# Add to set in C++

Tags: c++, set, addition

So, I want to know, how to do my code shorter:

```
  set<char> t;
  t.insert( 'a');
  t.insert( 'A');
  t.insert( 'o');
  t.insert( 'O');   
  t.insert( 'y');
  t.insert( 'Y');
  t.insert( 'e');
  t.insert( 'E');
  t.insert( 'u');
  t.insert( 'U');
  t.insert( 'i');
  t.insert( 'I');
  cout<<t.count('O');
```

I'm sure, thet is another way will be shorter and more correctly. What is the easiest way do you know?

Comment: Just `cout << 1;` ?

Comment: `set<char> t; char values[]="aAoOyYeEuUiI"; for (auto c:values) if (c) t.insert(c);`

Comment: BTW, typo: `incert` should be `insert` (for 'o', 'O').

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, no. It is easy problem: to count up, how many vowels in string; I write it, for example..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++11 initialization:

`std::set<char> t = {'a', <the rest>, 'I'};`

Comment: Then allow me to help you with that (-1) `;)`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...

std::set<char> t;
std::string s= "aAoOyYeEuUiI";

std::copy( s.begin() , s.end(), std::inserter(t, t.begin() ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Boost is an option - try the `assign` library.

Comment: As a hint, try to write the answer with an example, a link, enough explanation to make it better if you want to get reputations ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I am so lazy :( And I think that hints are better then simply an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set<char> t;
char v[] = {'a', 'o', 'y', 'e', 'u', 'i'};
for (int i = 0;  i < 6; ++i )
{
   t.insert(v[i]);
   t.insert(v[i]+'A'-'a');
}
```